# Kafka Schema Registry - StoreInitializationException: Timed out trying to create or validate schema topic configuration

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

i'm trying to configure schema registry to work with SSL, i have already zookeeper and kafka brokers working with the same SSL keys. 
but whenever i start the schema-registry i get the following error

```
ERROR Error starting the schema registry(io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication) 
      io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryInitializationException: Error initializing kafka store while initializing schema registry
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.exceptions.StoreInitializationException: Timed out trying to create or validate schema topic configuration
```

`schema-registry.properties` configuration :

```
listeners=https://IP:8081
kafkastore.connection.url=IP:2181
kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=SSL://IP:9092
kafkastore.topic=_schemas
kafkastore.topic.replication.factor=1
kafkastore.security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/.kafka_ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
ssl.keystore.location=/.kafka_ssl/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
inter.instance.protocol=https
```

can someone advise ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons that might cause this issue. Try to use a different topic for `kafkastore.topic` in case `_schemas` got corrupted.

---

For example,

```
kafkastore.topic=_schemas_new
```

Comment: i tried this option, also reconfigured and double checked the kafka andd zookeeper 
now im getting a new error i will update the Q

Comment: @LoayN StackOverflow doesn't work like this. Avoid updating the question in order to ask a different question. The problem that you had it has been solved. If you have another problem, ask a different question.